# Partial Rendering will only work with @form?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a strange situation where using @parent, or even explicit id-s dont work in the update attribute. But @form works fine.

I've made a very simple test case, that includes a simple grid whose behaviour is like this :

1. Every record inside the grid has a modify button
2. After the modify button is clicked, it'll modify the server data, and the button will be gone, since it'll be only rendered if the record has NOT been modified.

The modify button is like this :

```
<!-- this works, since it's using @form in the update attribute -->
<p:column>
    <p:commandLink
        value="modify record" 
        process="@this" 
        action="#{testUserBean.modifyRecord(user)}"
        update="@form"
        rendered="#{not testUserBean.isRecordModified(user)}" />
</p:column>
```

Notice that the update attribute makes use of @form which makes it work: when the modify button is clicked, it rerenders and disappears.

Substitute it with @this or @parent or the id of the grid, then it will NOT work. For me it's very logical to use the id of the grid in the update attribute, since i would like to refresh the grid after clicking on the buttton.
I tried making use of `rowIndexVar="rowIndex"` and `myGridId:#{rowIndex}:link`, but still aint working.

```
<!-- this does not work -->
<p:column>
    <p:commandLink id="link"
        value="modify record" 
        process="@this" 
        action="#{testUserBean.modifyRecord(user)}"
        update="tblUser"
        rendered="#{not testUserBean.isRecordModified(user)}" />
</p:column>
```

Here are the resources for this simple example :

1. [The xhtml file](http://pastebin.com/14csUs6F)
2. [The JSF Bean file](http://pastebin.com/JnPgMfmY)
3. [The user POJO bean](http://pastebin.com/AGf6UBmf)

Im using tomcat 7, and these are my dependencies :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4-b09</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4-b09</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Tried out primefaces 3.0.M1 also, but it got the same behavior also.

Please share your ideas. Is this a bug or i did something wrong ?

---

UPDATE

---

Hello,

I've just finished some testing, but all still fails.

**Test 1 (making use of `update=":gridRPBDetails"`) :**

*The JSF File :*

```
<p:commandLink id="undoLink" value="Undo" process="@this"
    action="#{tInputBean.actionUndoRemoveRecord(rpbDetail)}"
    update=":gridRPBDetails"
    rendered="#{tInputBean.isRemoveRecord(rpbDetail)}"
    title="Batalkan buang data" />
```

*The generated xhtml :*

```
<a title="Batalkan buang data" onclick="PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxRequest('/cashbank/faces/TInput.xhtml',
{formId:'j_idt38',async:false,global:true,source:'gridRPBDetails:0:undoLink',
process:'gridRPBDetails:0:undoLink',update:':gridRPBDetails'});" 
href="javascript:void(0);" id="gridRPBDetails:0:undoLink">Undo</a>
```

**Test 2 (making use of `update=":gridRPBDetails:#{rowIndex}:undoLink"`) :**

*The JSF File :*

```
<p:commandLink id="undoLink" value="Undo" process="@this"
    action="#{tInputBean.actionUndoRemoveRecord(rpbDetail)}"
    update=":gridRPBDetails:#{rowIndex}:undoLink"
    rendered="#{tInputBean.isRemoveRecord(rpbDetail)}"
    title="Batalkan buang data" />
```

*The generated xhtml :*

```
<a title="Batalkan buang data" onclick="PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxRequest('/cashbank/faces/TInput.xhtml',
{formId:'j_idt38',async:false,global:true,source:'gridRPBDetails:0:undoLink',
process:'gridRPBDetails:0:undoLink',update:':gridRPBDetails:0:undoLink'});" 
href="javascript:void(0);" id="gridRPBDetails:0:undoLink">Undo</a>
```

Both tests still fail in terms of clicking the undo button cannot refresh the record of the grid, or even the grid itself.

---

UPDATE

---

I've just updated my test using :

```
<p:commandLink
    value="modify record" 
    process="@this" 
    action="#{testUserBean.modifyRecord(user)}"
    update=":mainForm:tblUser"
    rendered="#{not testUserBean.isRecordModified(user)}" />
```

Notice i used the `:mainForm:tblUser`, and i've tried the other options and still failed :

1. :mainForm:tblUser:
2. :tblUser (when i dont define the form name)
3. :mainForm:tblUser:#{rowIndex}:linkId

But 1 thing i notice is,nNo matter what i choosed for the update, the update always ends up as **tblUser:0**

```
<a onclick="PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxRequest('/cashbank/faces/test.xhtml',
{formId:'mainForm',async:false,global:true,source:'tblUser:0:j_idt33',
  process:'tblUser:0:j_idt33',
  update:'tblUser:0'
});" href="javascript:void(0);" id="tblUser:0:j_idt33">modify record</a>
```

I tried modifying **tblUser:0** on the fly using firebug to just **tblUser**, the partial rendering on the grid works fine.

Im beginning to think that this is a bug when trying to update a grid from inside a grid record.

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been answered in [here](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10859).

Here is the quote from the answer :

> This is more like a mojarra issue, it should work fine with myfaces
>   without a wrapper. Workaround is to put a wrapper.

```
  Code:
    <h:form id="frm">
       <p:outputPanel id="wrapper">
           <p:dataTable id="tbl">
           //...
               <p:commandButton update=":frm:wrapper" />
           //...
           <p:dataTable>
       <p:outputPanel>
    </h:form>
```

Sorry for the late update !

Comment: Please accept this as the correct answer, so it stays at the top and people see it right away. The whole question would be difficult to follow otherwise.

Comment: @Tim Post: I usually accepted my answer. I just didnt realize that i can do this quite faster than before where i have to wait for 2 days to be able to tick my own answer. Thanks for the suggestions tho.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the generated HTML. Since the `<p:commandLink>` is placed in a `<p:dataTable>`, its generated client ID is something like this

```
<a id="someformid:tblUser:0:link">
```

The `0` is the table row index.

So when you use the relative identifier `update="tblUser"` on `<p:commandLink>`, then it will basically search for `someformid:tblUser:0:tblUser` to update. But this does not exist. You'd like to use an absolute identifier instead, starting with `:`.

```
<p:commandLink update=":someformid:tblUser">
```

Comment: Hello, BalusC. Thank you for the suggestion. I've updated my original post with the testing you recommended. Still failed, perhaps i did something wrong ?

Comment: You want to remove the row? You should really update the entire table.

Comment: Hello, yes, that's what i've tried out. This problem  seems to happen only when a grid record tries to update on the grid itself. Please see my updated answer for my latest test. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p:dataTable id="mytable"
       value="#{dataTableWithLinkBean.list}" var="item">
      <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
        Code
        </f:facet>
        <p:commandLink actionListener="#{dataTableWithLinkBean.viewDetail}"  
                oncomplete="dlg.show()" process="@this" 
                         update=":mainform:dialog_content">
            <h:outputText value="#{item.code}"/>
            <f:param name="code" value="#{item.code}"/>
        </p:commandLink>
      </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>



    <p:dialog widgetVar="dlg" modal="true" id="dialog"
         width="300" height="300">
    <h:panelGrid id="dialog_content">
         <h:outputText value="#{dataTableWithLinkBean.selectedCode}"/>
    </h:panelGrid>     
    </p:dialog>
```

Above is the example of link in the datatable that render the dialog.
may be you can try to change

update="**:mainform:dialog_content**"

to

update="**:mainform:mytable**"

in this case my tag form is using id mainform, shown as below:

Please note that I've not been trying this. I just have used in my example above to rendering the dialog panel partially. Good luck

**Update:**
Well I give it a try like this, combine with your updated post

```
 <p:dataTable id="mytable"
       value="#{dataTableWithLinkBean.list}" var="item">
      <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
        Code
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{item.code}"/>
      </p:column>
      <p:column>
        <p:commandLink value="Modify" 
               action="#{dataTableWithLinkBean.removeDetail(item)}"
               process="@this" 
               update="mytable"
               rendered="#{not dataTableWithLinkBean.isModifier(item)}">
        </p:commandLink>
      </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

And in the backing bean

```
     public String removeDetail(ClassForTest item){
    for(ClassForTest o: list){
        if(o.equals(item)){
            //do something update to database
            item.setModified(true);
            break;
        }
    }
    return "";
}

    public boolean isModifier(ClassForTest item){
    return item.isModified();
}
```

And it's worked! after I click on the modify button, call the removeDetail method, do some actions, update the modified status. then do update="mytable", and the link modify is gone.

I'm using Mojarra 2.0.4 and primefaces 3.0.M2

FYI, I'm using DataModel in the backing bean, just a simple List
so no rowIndexVar. Maybe when using the DataModel, can produce this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I've tried using the approach you suggested on other pages before i ever faced this problem, and indeed it worked fine. This problem of mine seems to happen only when a grid record tries to update on the grid itself. Please see my updated answer for my latest test.